# how to make sure HTML Websocket seesion keep alive in Android webview

Tags: android, webview, websocket

how to make sure HTML Websocket seesion keep alive  in Android webview when andriod device goes in sleep mode.My enitre application is running in web view.  I have used the below code:

```
 PowerManager  powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Httpd");
        wakeLock.acquire();

        // Keep the wifi awake.
        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager)this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiManager.WifiLock wifiLock = wm.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF, "Httpd");
          wifiLock.acquire();


        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

and below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Its disable the screen lock but still webssocket session is getting timeout some how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use wake lock permission,

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```